# Dependencies for jUnit 4.11 with JMock 2.6 and Hamcrest 1.3

Tags: junit, jmock, hamcrest

I'm using a combination of JUnit 4.8 JMock 2.5.1 and Hamcrest 1.1.
Now I wanna upgrade to jUnit 4.11 with JMock 2.6 and Hamcrest 1.3.

Cause JUnit 4.11 comes with hamcrest 1.3.
I only import JUnit 4.11 and JMock trough my dependency management.

dependency org="org.jmock" name="jmock-legacy" rev="2.6.0" conf="test->*" transitive="true" 
dependency org="org.jmock" name="jmock-junit4" rev="2.6.0" conf="test->*" transitive="true"

dependency org="junit" name="junit" rev="4.11" conf="test->default"

But I get strange behavior running my tests in this combination like:

```
java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7.getAssignedPermissionValues(Unknown Source)
at permissions.xml.UserRolePermissionsTest$2.<init>(UserRolePermissionsTest.java:80)
at permissions.xml.UserRolePermissionsTest.emptyPermissionInfosAreSilentlyIgnoredByConstructor(UserRolePermissionsTest.java:78)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.jmock.integration.junit4.JUnitRuleMockery$1.evaluate(JUnitRuleMockery.java:49)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)

Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.util.EnumSet
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:359)
at org.jmock.internal.ReturnDefaultValueAction.collectionOrMapInstanceFor(ReturnDefaultValueAction.java:87)
at org.jmock.internal.ReturnDefaultValueAction.invoke(ReturnDefaultValueAction.java:77)
at org.jmock.internal.InvocationToExpectationTranslator.invoke(InvocationToExpectationTranslator.java:20)
at org.jmock.internal.FakeObjectMethods.invoke(FakeObjectMethods.java:38)
at org.jmock.lib.JavaReflectionImposteriser$1.invoke(JavaReflectionImposteriser.java:33)
... 28 more
```

Can someone please provide the right dependencies I need. Or explain what I make wrong.

Regards and thanks

Answer (score 0):

This works for me: jmock-junit4 will introduce junit-dep:4.4 if I'm not mistaken（which will not be omitted with junit:4.11, artifactId differs）.

```
<!-- general test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.RC2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jmock</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmock-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>junit-dep</artifactId>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```